# Имя сетевого интерфейса в переменной bash

Tags: linux, bash

Задача стоит написать скрипт,который будет вносить изменения в сетевые настройки.Не могу понять как получить имя сетевого интерфейса в переменную.Т.к. нужно будет раскинуть данный скрипт по многим машинам,что бы не вводить каждый раз интерфейс вручную.Все это нужно сделать на bash
Из вариантов которые есть - это брать команду ifconfig -a и с нее пытаться вытащить название интерфейса

Comment: `ls /sys/class/net` ; `for iface in \`ls /sys/class/net\`; do echo $iface; done`

Comment: если у вас больше чем 2 сервера смотрите в сторону Ansible/Pupe/Chef/Salt и им подобным системам 21  век ведь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**: (Thanks to @nobody)

```
ls /sys/class/net
```

**2**:

```
ip -o link show | awk '{print $2,$9}'
```

**3**:

```
nmcli dev status
```

**4**:

```
nmcli --terse --fields DEVICE,STATE dev status
```

**5**:

```
ifconfig | cut -d ' ' -f1| tr ':' '\n' | awk NF
```

---

Выбирайте тот вариант, который вам нравится больше всего.

---

Источники: AskUbuntu, Unix&Linux

Answer (score 1):

Кусок рабочего скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IPv4_RE="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
MAC_RE="([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})"
UP=$'\e[32m▲ UP\e[39m'
DOWN=$'\e[31m▼ DOWN\e[39m'


_net_if()
{ # Return a list of avaialable physical network interfaces
    ls "/sys/class/net" \
       -I "bon*" \
       -I "lo*" \
       -I "vir*" \
       -I "vnet*" \
       -I "macvtap*" \
       -I "br-*" \
       -I "docker*"
}

_net_str()
{ # Return a string information of a physical inteface
    local interface="$1"

    # <ipv4> <mac> <status>
    {
        echo "$interface"
        ip a show "${interface}" \
            | grep -oP ".*(?= brd )" \
            | grep -oP "$IPv4_RE"

        cat "/sys/class/net/${interface}/address"

        if [[ "$(cat "/sys/class/net/${interface}/operstate")" = up ]]; then
            printf "%s" "${UP}"
        else
            printf "%s" "${DOWN}"
        fi
    } | paste -sd " " -
}

chk_net_inf()
{ #
    local num

    num=0

    for net in $(_net_if); do
        printf "NET-${num}\t: %s\n" "$(_net_str "$net")"
        let "num++"
    done
}

main()
{
    chk_net_inf
}

main "$@"
```

Результат

```
~$ ./interfaces.sh
NET-0   : enp2s0 192.168.1.69 bc:5f:f4:ee:1d:b2 ▲ UP
```

Каждую функцию можно привязать к переменной-массиву в Bash

`_net_if` - фильтрует все возможные интерфейсы от "виртуальных" и выдает только "железные"

Answer (score 0):

Вот эта функция будет определять интерфейс через который ходят в Интернет:

```
ext_interface () {
    for interface in /sys/class/net/*
    do
        [[ "${interface##*/}" != 'lo' ]] && \
            ping -c1 -W2 -I "${interface##*/}" 208.67.222.222 >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
                printf '%s' "${interface##*/}" && return 0
    done
}

interface=$(ext_interface)
```

Comment: 'ip route | grep default' так вроде проще

Comment: @Hellseher, вывод сравните. Это первое, второе, а если у вас в инет смотрит не дефолтный интерфейс?