# Вывести состояние режима работы беспроводного интерфейса (iwconfig)

Tags: kali-linux

Товарищи, приветствую!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно корректно применить фильтр поиска для отображения информации о режиме работы сетевых беспроводных интерфейсов?

```
    root@kali19:~# iwconfig
    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
              Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Encryption key:off
              Power Management:off
```

нужно чтобы выводилось только **wlan0 Mode:Managed**, а если их несколько, то в столбик.

wlan0 Mode:Managed
wlan1 Mode:Monitor

Как например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/913189/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-bash)
Спасибо.

---

Сделал только для одного интерфейса:

```
iwconfig wlan0  2> /dev/null | grep Mode: | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Вот как сделать для всех, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте подредактировать мой скрипт по ссылке

Comment: @Hellseher мне бы хотелось всё таки использовать простейшую команду, именно команду в терминале, если заняться скрипом, то какая часть мне больше всего подойдёт? эта
```
    echo "$interface"
    ip a show "${interface}" \
    | grep -oP ".*(?= brd )" \
    | grep -oP "$IPv4_RE"
    cat "/sys/class/net/${interface}/address"
```

Comment: `ip a | grep wlan -C2 | grep -o "wlan[0-9]\|Mode:.* " | column -t`

Comment: @Hellseher Вы прислали уже готовый вариант, или тот, который необходимо подредактировать?

Comment: Проверте каждую команду по `man` и почитайте про конвеер в Unix.

Comment: @Hellseher, хорошо, спасибо, попробую что-нибудь наковырять. Но хотелось бы уже готовый вариант, если таковой имеется.

Comment: Пробуйте и все получится.

Comment: @Hellseher, к сожалению, пока ни чего толкового не выходит :(